# Jquery not working with razor to update data inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm having a problem while trying to mix bootstrap/razor/jquery to CRUD a simple system users page.

I'm display the data using razor:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h2>Account Management</h2>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="modal">

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="t_users" class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table"
                       data-height="460"
                       data-pagination="true"
                       data-search="true">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.username)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.emailConfirmed)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.roles)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Ações
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.username)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emailConfirmed)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.roles)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="edit btn btn-info btn-xs" data-id="@item.id" id="btEdit">Editar</button>
                            <button class="remove btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-id="@item.id" id="btRemove">Remover</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            </div>
        <button id="teste">bugabuga</button>
        </div>
```

My idea is to link the "click' action of the update button to send to my controller the row data-id which is the user's id then open a modal with a form (PartialView) so the user can update the data.

Here's the javascript, please note that I did a test to just display an alert window.

```
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    });

    $("#btEdit").click(function () {
        alert("dig");

    });

    $(".edit").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $("#modal").load("AccountManager/Update?id=" + id, function () {
            $("#modal").modal();
        })
    });
</script>
}
```

the call to open the modal is not working. When I click it nothing happens.

```
 $("#modal").load("AccountManager/Update?id=" + id, function () {
            $("#modal").modal();
        })
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: I'll edit the post but is the call to open the modal.
$("#modal").load("AccountManager/Update?id=" + id, function () {
            $("#modal").modal();
        })

Comment: what is happening when you click ?

Comment: If you are not getting id value, can you please try and see what you get for `var id = $(this).data("id");`

Comment: @Shyju Nothing happens, no errors on the console either.

Comment: Is it making the call ? check network tab. Also you should register the click event on the document ready. Take a look at the answer i posted

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan I can't because the function is never called.

Comment: @Shyju the network tab is showing that nothing happens.

Comment: Put ` $(".edit").click(function () {....` inside the `document.ready`

Comment: @RaphaelLima The code in my answer is working (verified in a local project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. It should work as long as you do not have any js errors and you have the needed library js files loaded. But you can still make few improvements.

Do not hardcode the Id values in the loop. It will generate more than one element with same id value. Id values should be unique.

Also instead of building the url to the action method in javascript, you might consider using the Html helper methods to generate the correct relative path to the action method.

```
<button class="edit btn btn-info btn-xs" 
       data-url="@Url.Action("Update","AccountManager",new { id=item.id})" >Edit</button>
```

Now on the click event, read the data-url value and use that for the ajax call.

```
$(function(){

    $(".edit").click(function () {
        var ajaxUrl= $(this).data("url");
        $("#modal").load(ajaxUrl, function () {
            $("#modal").modal();
        })
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please move your click event binding inside `document.ready` first, otherwise it wont be fired until you bind them somewhere.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".edit").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#modal").load("AccountManager/Update?id=" + id, function () {
        $("#modal").modal();
    })
  });

});
```